# Why is Powershell not looping through list of computers when copying files?

Tags: powershell, psexec

I have a little script that takes a list of computers and saves a couple of files to each computer on the list.  If the user enters option 1, it saves a program.exe and Install.ps1 file to the C:\ of the remote computer.
The program.exe usually takes a minute or 2 because it is kind of big.

As of right now, the 2 files are only saved to the first computer on my list.  It doesn't move onto the next computer after the first is done.  Is there a reason why it is doing this?  Do I have to tell PowerShell to wait until the first computer is complete?

The CopyFiles function is the function in question.

Here is my code.

```
cls #clear screen

function CopyFiles {

    # Get .exe from source and place at destination workstation
    $source2="\\mainserver\program.exe"
    $destination2="\\$line\c$\program.exe"           # place .exe on C:\ directory of worstation
    Copy-Item -Recurse -Filter *.* -path $source2 -destination $destination2 -Force

    # Get .bat from source and place at destination workstation
    $source3="\\fileserver\Install.ps1"
    $destination3="\\$line\c$\Install.ps1"  # place .bat on C:\ directory of worstation
    Copy-Item -Recurse -Filter *.* -path $source3 -destination $destination3 -Force
}

$a = Get-Content "C:\myscript\computers.txt"
foreach($line in $a)
{

  "These options must run in numbered order."
  " "
  " "
  "1. Copy installer to remote computer(s)."
  "2. Remove application from remote computer(s)."
  "3. Install application from remote computer(s)."
  "4. Quit."
  " "
  "Type number and press Enter." 
  $UI = Read-Host -Prompt ' '

  If ($UI -eq 1) {
    CopyFiles
  } ELSEIF ($UI -eq 2) {
  psexec @C:\myscript\computers.txt -c "\\fileserver\Remove.bat"
  } ELSEIF ($UI -eq 3) {
  psexec -s @C:\myscript\computers.txt cmd /c "Powershell Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy Bypass && PowerShell -noninteractive -file "C:\Install.ps1""
  } ELSEIF ($UI -eq 4) {
  "Good Bye"
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to do the same action on each computer? You should move the "UI" logic out of the loop. As it's written now, it prompts for input before it does an action on each computer.

Comment: Your right.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You want to copy the files in all the remote computers so you have to move the prompt outside of the `foreach` to be called just once else you will prompt for every computer. You also can pass the list of computers in the function.

```
cls #clear screen

function Copy-Files {
  Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string[]]
    $Hostnames
  )

  foreach ($computer in $Hostnames) {
    # Get .exe from source and place at destination workstation
    $source2 = "\\mainserver\program.exe"
    $destination2 = "\\$computer\c$\program.exe"           # place .exe on C:\ directory of worstation
    Copy-Item -Recurse -Filter *.* -path $source2 -destination $destination2 -Force

    # Get .bat from source and place at destination workstation
    $source3 = "\\fileserver\Install.ps1"
    $destination3 = "\\$computer\c$\Install.ps1"  # place .bat on C:\ directory of worstation
    Copy-Item -Recurse -Filter *.* -path $source3 -destination $destination3 -Force
  }
}

"These options must run in numbered order."
" "
" "
"1. Copy installer to remote computer(s)."
"2. Remove application from remote computer(s)."
"3. Install application from remote computer(s)."
"4. Quit."
" "
"Type number and press Enter." 

$listComputers = Get-Content "C:\myscript\computers.txt"
$UI = Read-Host -Prompt ' '

If ($UI -eq 1) {
    Copy-Files -Hostnames $listComputers
}
ELSEIF ($UI -eq 2) {
    psexec @C:\myscript\computers.txt -c "\\fileserver\Remove.bat"
}
ELSEIF ($UI -eq 3) {
    psexec -s @C:\myscript\computers.txt cmd /c "Powershell Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy Bypass && PowerShell -noninteractive -file "C:\Install.ps1""
}
ELSEIF ($UI -eq 4) {
    "Good Bye"
}
```